# simplest way to make div fadeOut

Tags: jquery, function, html, slider, fadeout

It's probably because I haven't been getting enough sleep, but I just can't figure this out. I'm trying to make a page where you have multiple videos, and then there's a div on top that appears suddenly and fades as the video is loading, all of this `onClick`. I had it earlier today, but now it's not working. The part of the function is

```
$('#hh').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 0, function() {
            myVideo.src = videos[numb];
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
     $('#hh').fadeOut(400);                                                        
    });
```

so, why isn't this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#hh').show();
myVideo.src = videos[numb];
myVideo.load();
myVideo.play();
$('#hh').fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

.fadeOut is a pretty easy way to get things to fade out.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration parameter is omitted, the default duration of 400 milliseconds is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('TARGET').fadeOut(300); // TARGET is any valid selector
```

**[fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**

```
   $('#hh').show('fast', function() {
         myVideo.src = videos[numb];
         myVideo.load();
         myVideo.play();
         $(this).fadeOut(400);                                                        
    });
```

also you can use

```
   $('#hh').fadeIn('fast', function() {
         myVideo.src = videos[numb];
         myVideo.load();
         myVideo.play();
         $(this).fadeOut(400);                                                        
    });
```

**[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)**

Comment: A 0ms `show()` renders no animation and therefore requires no callback. This is confusing and redundant for the OP.

Comment: Sorry again, but `show('fast', ..` is not the same as `fadeIn()` as you'll see it grows as it fades in with that technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the your code with,

```
    $('#hh').fadeIn('slow', function() {

                   // Call Back Function 

                   myVideo.src = videos[numb];
                   myVideo.load();
                   myVideo.play();
                   $('#hh').fadeOut('slow');                            
        }                            
    });
```

But there is one thing that I have not understood, is that why you want to set opacity 0 after `myVideo.play();`

Comment: He is displaying a div that probably says "loading video" while the video is loading, and it disappears when the video starts playing.

Comment: @davidaam that's basically it

Answer (score 0):

You could use fadeIn, in the callback change your video src, load and play, and finally fadeOut. It should work

```
$('#hh').fadeIn(400, function () {
  myVideo.src = videos[numb];
  myVideo.load();
  myVideo.play();
  $(this).fadeOut(400);    
});
```